# Adding limit to sequelize findAll destroys the query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to return a group of `Model`s, paginated using `limit` and `offset`, including the grouped count of that model's favorites. A fairly trivial thing to attempt.

Here's my basic query setup with sequelize:

```
var perPage = 12;
var page = 1;

return Model.findAll({

    group: [ 'model.id', 'favorites.id' ],
    attributes: [
        '*',
        [ Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('favorites.id')), 'favorites_count' ]
    ],
    include: [
        { attributes: [], model: Favorite },
    ],
    offset: perPage * page
```

This generates the (fairly) expected query:

```
SELECT          "model"."id",
                "model".*,
                Count("favorites"."id") AS "favorites_count",
                "favorites"."id"        AS "favorites.id"
FROM            "model"                 AS "model"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "favorite"              AS "favorites"
ON              "model"."id" = "favorites"."model_id"
GROUP BY        "model"."id",
                "favorites"."id" offset 12;
```

Ignoring the fact that it quotes the tables, and that it selects `favorites.id` (forcing me to add it to the group by clause), and that it has randomly aliased things to their exact name or to a nonsensical name like `"favorites.id"` (all undesired), it seems to have worked. But now let's complete the pagination and add the limit to the query:

```
...
offset: perPage * page
limit: perPage
```

It now generates this query:

```
SELECT "model".*,
    "favorites"."id" AS "favorites.id"
FROM   (SELECT "model"."id",
            "model".*,
            Count("favorites"."id") AS "favorites_count"
        FROM   "model" AS "model"
        GROUP  BY "model"."id",
                "favorites"."id"
        LIMIT  12 offset 12) AS "model"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "favorite" AS "favorites"
                    ON "model"."id" = "favorites"."model";
```

In completely baffling behavior, it has generated an inner query and applied the limit only to that, then aliased that as `"model"`.

As a sanity check I looked in the docs for findAll, but the docs [do not seem to think that command exists](https://readthedocs.org/elasticsearch/?q=findall&type=file&project=sequelize&version=latest).

I suspect I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. This behavior is quite bizzarre, and I'm hoping my sleep deprivation is the cause of my confusion.

I'm using version `2.0.6`

Comment: The command does exist in docs docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models/  but in https://readthedocs.org

Comment: Note: that the search in docs seems to be case-sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Sequelize. See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3623 and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/3671